# Not able to remove the black screen at loding view in android app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask

I have this problem, when I try to load new view, before I get service response I get black screen. Now to solve this issue I have used AsyncTask and I have solved the issue but the problem is I'm not getting Output from my service. Below is my code.

```
class GetInfo extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    /**
             * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
             * */
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewHomeView.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            /**
             * Creating player
             * */
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {



                        goal = MMBusinessFacade.baseURL;
                        goal = goal + "getGoal.jsp?acno=" + acnt;
                        goal = goal.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
                        res = MMBusinessFacade.getXML(goal, NewHomeView.this);
                        NewHomeView.res1 = gp.getOutput(res);
                        System.out.println("URL:" + goal);
                        System.out.println("Output:" + res1);


                        /********************************************************************************************/
                        spnrshi1 = MMBusinessFacade.baseURL;
                        spnrshi1 = spnrshi1 + "getFunds.jsp?acno=" + acnt;
                        spnrshi1 = spnrshi1.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
                        res = MMBusinessFacade.getXML(spnrshi1, NewHomeView.this);
                        System.out.println("URL" + spnrshi1);
                        list1 = fdp.getOutputOrg1(res);
                        list = fdp.getOutputOrg(res);

                        if (list1 != null && list1.size() > 0) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < list1.size(); j++) {
                                FundsAvailable prpobj = (FundsAvailable) list1.get(j);
                                FundDetail prpobj1 = (FundDetail) list.get(j);
                                ite = prpobj.getAmount() + "  " + prpobj.getCurrency();
                                System.out.println("Item:" + ite);
                                NewHomeView.favail = prpobj1.getAmount() + " " + prpobj1.getCurrency();
                                NewHomeView.cur = prpobj.getCurrency();
                            }
                        }



                return null;
      }
            /**
             * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
             * **/
            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) 
            {
                // dismiss the dialog once done
                pDialog.dismiss();
                gl.setText(NewHomeView.res1);
                avilfund.setText(NewHomeView.ite);
                fndraised.setText(NewHomeView.favail);
            }

        }
```

Plz give your valuable advise.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think:
U should not use runOnUiThread in doInBackground function.Otherwise,doInBackground will return immediately。And you will get null with onPostExecute(null).So,failed.
right code:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

                        goal = MMBusinessFacade.baseURL;
                        goal = goal + "getGoal.jsp?acno=" + acnt;
                        goal = goal.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
                        res = MMBusinessFacade.getXML(goal, NewHomeView.this);
                        NewHomeView.res1 = gp.getOutput(res);
                        System.out.println("URL:" + goal);
                        System.out.println("Output:" + res1);


                        /********************************************************************************************/
                        spnrshi1 = MMBusinessFacade.baseURL;
                        spnrshi1 = spnrshi1 + "getFunds.jsp?acno=" + acnt;
                        spnrshi1 = spnrshi1.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
                        res = MMBusinessFacade.getXML(spnrshi1, NewHomeView.this);
                        System.out.println("URL" + spnrshi1);
                        list1 = fdp.getOutputOrg1(res);
                        list = fdp.getOutputOrg(res);

                        if (list1 != null && list1.size() > 0) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < list1.size(); j++) {
                                FundsAvailable prpobj = (FundsAvailable) list1.get(j);
                                FundDetail prpobj1 = (FundDetail) list.get(j);
                                ite = prpobj.getAmount() + "  " + prpobj.getCurrency();
                                System.out.println("Item:" + ite);
                                NewHomeView.favail = prpobj1.getAmount() + " " + prpobj1.getCurrency();
                                NewHomeView.cur = prpobj.getCurrency();
                            }
                        }

           }
      }
```

Comment: hey mate I have already try n remove the runOnUiThread and new Runnable() and public void run() it help to remove black screen but I'm not getting my service response. and thats the issue I'm facing.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `runOnUiThread` in your `doInBackground`, it make you loose interest in using AsyncTask. The best way to communicate with UI in doInBackground is to use the progress update process:

just implement in your asynTask:

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(MyProgressObject... mpo) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(mpo);
    //my UI update here
}
```

and when you need to update UI from within `doInBackground` just call `publishProgress(MyProgressObject mpo)`

Comment: I have already removed it and it helps to remove the black screen however, Actually I'm using Async-task within Async-task.